# Difference between Lyapunov and uniform stability

Tags: dynamical-systems, stability-in-odes

I'm trying to understand the difference between general Lyapunov stability and uniform stability.

I understand, that Lyapunov s. is the situation, when for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta > 0$, such that when the solution starts within a distance $\delta$ from the equilibrium point, it remains within a distance $\epsilon$ from it forever.

But I don't get, what's the difference with uniform stability at all. I've found some info on [this site](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Uniform_stability), but still I don't get it.

Could you, please, explain it to me in some intuitive way?

Comment: Really your link (from a well respected encyclopaedia) says it all: copying from it, uniform stability is "Lyapunov stability, uniform with respect to the initial time". That means that $\delta$ can be chosen independently of the initial time.

Comment: To get a better grip than provided in these answers, I found it helpful to work through the fairly-readable (as readable as you can get in nonautonomous systems I guess) resource http://www.cds.caltech.edu/~murray/courses/cds101/fa02/caltech/mls93-lyap.pdf

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The concept of *uniform stability* is mainly defined for non-autonomous systems, i.e. the systems of the form
$$\dot x = f(t,x),$$
but *Lyapunov stability* or what is often called just *stability* is defined for both autonomous systems and non-autonomous systems.

We first assume that the system is non-autonomous and let $x_0(t)$ be solution of $\dot x = f(t,x)$ starting at $x_0(t_0)$. Then we have the following definitions [*Khalil, Hassan K.*, Nonlinear systems., Upper Saddle River, NJ: Prentice Hall. xv, 750 p. (2002). [ZBL1003.34002](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1003.34002).]:

- $\textbf{Lyapunov stability (stability)}$: for each $\varepsilon>0$, there is $\delta=\delta(\mathbf{\epsilon,t_0})>0$ such that
  $$\|x(t_0)-x_0(t_0)\|<\delta~~\Rightarrow ~~\|x(t)-x_0(t)\|<\epsilon, ~~\forall t\geq t_0\geq0$$
- $\textbf{Uniform stability}$: for each $\varepsilon>0$, there is $\delta=\delta(\mathbf{\epsilon})>0$, $\textbf{independent of}$ $\mathbf{t_0}$, such that
  $$\|x(t_0)-x_0(t_0)\|<\delta~~\Rightarrow ~~\|x(t)-x_0(t)\|<\epsilon, ~~\forall t\geq t_0\geq0$$

Note that the only difference is in the definition of $\delta$, where for uniform stability, $\delta$ is independent of $t_0$.

For autonomous system, $\dot x = f(x)$, uniform stability is the same as Lyapunov stability because $f$ is not explicitly a function of $t$.

Comment: which is sense of stability is more strict for a non-autonomous system? Lyapunov or Uniform?

Answer (score 0):

Let us consider the following nonlinear system $$\dot x = f(t,x),\ x(t_0)=x_0,$$
and assume that there is a unique solution starting from $x_0$ at time $t_0$. Let $\phi(t,t_0,x_0)$ be that solution.

Let $x^*$ be an equilibrium for this system, i.e. $f(t,x^*)=0$ for all $t\ge t_0$. Then, we have the following definitions

- The equilibrium point $x^*$ is **stable** if for each $\varepsilon>0$, there is $\delta=\delta(\mathbf{\epsilon,t_0})>0$ such that
  $$\|x_0-x^*\|<\delta~~\Rightarrow ~~\|\phi(t,t_0,x_0)-x^*\|<\epsilon, ~~\forall t\geq t_0\geq0$$
- The equilibrium point $x^*$ is **uniformly stable** if for each $\varepsilon>0$, there is $\delta=\delta(\mathbf{\epsilon})>0$ such that
  $$\|x_0-x^*\|<\delta~~\Rightarrow ~~\|\phi(t,t_0,x_0)-x^*\|<\epsilon, ~~\forall t\geq t_0\geq0$$

Note that the only difference is in the definition of $\delta$, where for uniform stability, $\delta$ is independent of $t_0$.

Comment: The other answer *is* correct, -1.

Comment: @Artem Nope, I'll explain that tomorrow when I will be on my computer. Some notations are not correct and those "definitions" are not in the book by Khalil. For instance the difference between $x(t)$ and $x_0(t)$ is meaningless. Finally, the question is about stability of equilibrium points and there is nothing about equilibrium points in the other answer. Check the book by Khalil if you like.

Comment: Dear @KBS. If one desires, one can always find something "incorrect" in other's writings. In general, the definition of stability by Lyapunov is a definition about a solution (not necessarily an equilibrium); and the difference between two solutions ($x(t)$ and $x_0(t)$ makes perfect sense). I never read Khalil book, but I am pretty sure about my knowledge of the basics of Lyapunov stability theory.

Comment: @Artem $x_0(t)$ is not defined to be a solution of the system but the initial condition in the other answer.

Comment: The person is just mistyped. I even did not pay any attention to this until your remark. You should read it as "let $x_0(t)$ be a solution, then it is Lyapunov stable if... it is uniformly Lyapunov stable if..."

Comment: But technically you are correct, and if you edit your answer, I will take away this -1.

Comment: @Artem I will do that tomorrow.

Comment: Gentle men, I agree with KBS on his corrections.

Comment: @Artem I have fixed the post and also corrected the other one.