# Stability definition

Tags: dynamical-systems, stability-in-odes, stability-theory

An equilibrium $x^*$ is said to be stable iff for all $\epsilon>0$, there exist $\delta>0$ s.t. $|x(0)-x^*|<\delta$ $\implies$ for all $t>0$, $|x(t)-x^*|<\epsilon.$

Does anyone know if the delta in the above definition of stability depends on $t$ and $\epsilon$ or only on $\epsilon$ ?

Comment: $\delta$ cannot depend on $t$ (but it obviously depends on $\epsilon$).

Comment: @NickD So, what is the difference between stability and uniform stability ?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2031460/difference-between-lyapunov-and-uniform-stability

Comment: @Hans Lundmark Thanks for your help!

Comment: @ Hans Lundmark Is there an error in the definition you gave me ? because it is written $||x(t)-x_0(t)||<\epsilon$ should it be $||x(t)-x_0(t_0)||<\epsilon$ where $x_0(t_0)$ is the equilibrium point ??

Comment: Better ask the answerer over there. But if it's an equilibrium, then $x_0(t)=x_0(t_0)$ for all $t$...

Comment: @ Hans Lundmark Ok i'll ask thank you!

Comment: If the epsilon $\epsilon$ and delta $\delta$ depend on time, then they should be written as $\epsilon(t), \delta(t)$ but they don't. they are constant positive values. In the other words, the initial value and the trajectory (the solution of an ODE) are bounded.