# Equivalence of Lyapunov Stability and Uniform Stability for Autonomous Systems

Tags: dynamical-systems, stability-in-odes

I have been trying to understand exactly how would would formally demonstrate the equivalence between uniform stability and Lyapunov stability for fixed points of autonomous systems.

First, apologies if I commit some formatting error or other faux-pas here on my first post.

I have found the excellent explanation given here, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2353040 , by M3053. I find this explanation intuitively satisfying, but I have been struggling without success to rigorously demonstrate this equivalence for myself. Moreover, all the references I have consulted so far seem content to state this equivalence as an obvious fact which unfortunately has not been so trivial for me to establish.

If anyone would be willing to elaborate upon the above explanation further, and provide some insight as to how it would be appropriate to go about demonstrating this equivalence, I would be grateful.

Comment: Exercise: let $\dot u=f(u)$ and $t\mapsto \phi(t)$ solves this equation. Show that $t\mapsto \phi(t+C)$ also solves it for any constant $C$.

Comment: First, thank you for your assistance.

Next, in trying to reply in what I understand to be the informative spirit of these boards, I believe I understand that to be so on the grounds that, letting p = t + C, we have

$$\dfrac{d(\phi(x+C))}{d(x+C)} = \dfrac{d(\phi(p))}{dp} = f(\phi(p)) = f(\phi(x+C)) $$

I got the impression that from this insight, I ought to be able to deduce that, given a Lyapunov stable fixed point and some particular $\delta(t_{0}, \epsilon)$ for any particular $t_{0}$, that this same $\delta$ will in fact suffice for any other initial time.

Comment: Phew, did my best with the formatting there, ha ha.

Anyway, on that basis I have been contemplating how to see this connection for a couple of hours, also without success. At this point it seems natural to ask, did I even get your meaning right from the hint you provided, or have I actually been chasing my tail so far?


P.S. Please note my error in the above where I wrote "x+C" repeatedly, just after saying let p = t+C. My window to edit expired before I noticed, so please just mentally replace the erroneous instances of "x+C" with "t+C".

Comment: Yes, that's the whole point: if the system is autonomous you can choose your initial condition at *any* point $t$, which automatically means that stability implies uniform stability.