# Are these two definitions of Lyapunov stability equivalent

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stability-in-odes, stability-theory

In our class on stability theory we had the following defintion of Lyapunov stability:

> Suppose we have a function $f:[a,\infty)\times G\to \mathbb{R}^n$ where $G$ is a connected open set in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $a\in \mathbb{R}$. Moreover, suppose that for any $(t_0,x_0) \in [a,+\infty)\times G$, the initial value problem $$x'(t)=f\left(t,x(t)\right), x(t_0)=x_0$$ has unique solution, denoted by $\phi(t,t_0,x_0)$.
>
> Then a solution $\psi(t)$ of $x'(t)=f\left(t,x(t)\right)$ is Lyapunov stable iff:
> $$\forall \epsilon>0, \forall t_0\ge a, \exists \delta>0, \forall x_0\in G: \|x_0-\psi(t_0)\|<\delta\implies (\forall t\ge t_0:\|\phi(t,t_0,x_0)-\psi(t)\|<\epsilon).$$

Now, I've also stumbled upon another definition of Lyapunov stability, which is:

> Suppose we have a function $f:[a,\infty)\times G\to \mathbb{R}^n$ where $G$ is a connected open set in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $a\in \mathbb{R}$. Moreover, suppose that for any $(t_0,x_0)\in[a,+\infty)\times G$, the initial value problem $$x'(t)=f\left(t,x(t)\right), x(t_0)=x_0$$ has unique solution, denoted by $\phi(t,t_0,x_0)$.
> Then a solution $\psi(t)$ of $x'(t)=f\left(t,x(t)\right)$ is Lyapunov stable iff:
> $$\forall \epsilon>0, \exists \delta>0, \forall x_0\in G: \|x_0-\psi(a)\|<\delta\implies (\forall t\ge a:\|\phi(t,a,x_0)-\psi(t)\|<\epsilon)$$

My question is the following: Are these two definitions equivalent ? If not, which one of those is the standard one ?

Comment: No, they are not equivalent. The second one is the definition for the uniform Lyapunov stability. Maybe this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2031460/difference-between-lyapunov-and-uniform-stability) can be of some help.

Comment: @Artem It seems to me that the second definition is not the defintion of uniform Lyapunov stability from the post linked by you, as in the second definition $a$ is fixed and in the definition of uniform Lyapunov stability $t_0$ is not fixed.

Comment: @ЮрійЯрош Those definitions are very unclear. Usually, the definitions of stability are with respect to an equilibrium point but they can also be with respect to a trajectory. This is not clear here. Also, you have $x(t_0)-x_0$ but those are states are equal and, as a result, the difference is just zero. So, I guess this post has a lot of typos that make the overall point unclear. Where did you find those stability notions? Please always provide a source whenever possible.

Comment: @KBS Yes, you are right, I've used the same notation for two different things which caused the confusion. Thanks for noting the problem. I will edit the post.

Comment: @ЮрійЯрош Please also define what $a$ and $x(t)$ are in the first statement and check everything to make sure that there is no more typos.

Comment: @Artem The answer you are suggesting does not seem to be correct and there is no such definitions in Khalil.

Comment: These definitions are more about continuity of solutions than stability about an equilibrium.

Comment: @copper.hat Yes and that's not what Lyapunov stability is about usually. This is the reason why I am suspecting some issues somewhere. So, I am trying to make sure that the question is correct and that there is no confusion at this level.

Comment: @ЮрійЯрош Could you also please mention where you found the second definition?

Comment: @KBS Богданський Ю.В. Диференціальні рівняння: Навч.посіб. – К.: ІВЦ „Видавництво „політехніка””, 2011, page 145 
Unfortunately, to my knowledge there is no English translation.

Comment: Ok I have checked the document and yes this definition is indeed regarding stability of two solutions with respect to each other. This is, in some sense, more connected the concept of contraction analysis.

Comment: @KBS Why do you say this is about stability of $\textbf{two}$ solutions with respect to each other ?

Comment: @ЮрійЯрош Is it the text you mention? http://mmsa.kpi.ua/sites/default/files/publications/%D0%91%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D0%AE%D1%80%D1%96%D0%B9%20%D0%92%D1%96%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87/bogdanskii-yu-v-differential-equations-tutorial.pdf If so, this is written there.

Comment: @KBS Yes, it is the text I mention. But on the page 145 the Lyapunov stability definition talks about stability of one solution only, namely $\phi(t,x_0)$ (in the notation of the text, not the notation I've introduced in the question) ?

Comment: From what I can see, two solutions starting from two different initial conditions and the stability is about the maximum distance between the trajectories provided that the initial conditions are chosen close enough. I cannot read the text but this is what the equations are saying, but some notations are ambiguous such as $x$ which is both used in the definition of the system and as an initial condition.

Comment: @KBS Ok, I can see what you mean when you say that it is about two soutions, but the thing is that one of those soutions is fixed and the other is taken to be any solution with close enough initial condition. That's why I am confused when you say that it is about stability of one solution with respect to the other, as the other solution is not fixed.

Comment: Both solutions are fixed as they are uniquely determined by their initial conditions even if one initial condition is allowed to be within some set around the other.

Comment: But the definition dictates for the property of being close enough under close enough initial conditions to hold for any of the soutions with close enough intial conditions. So I don't see why you say that the other solution is fixed.

Comment: It's not because the initial condition is in a set that the solution is not fixed. The solution is fixed as long as the initial condition is chosen. You can have a family of fixed solutions if you prefer.

Comment: I was wrong, they do not appear to be equivalent.

Comment: Not directly relevant here, but might provide an example where the second holds but the first does not: "Finite Time Differential Equations", V. T. Haimo,

Comment: @copper.hat From what I see is that in the first one, the constant $\delta$ depends on $t_0$ whereas in the second one that term is independent of the initial time (uniform stability).

Comment: @KBS The first one says that it is 'stable' starting from any initial time ($\ge a$) whereas the second says that it is 'stable' starting from $a$. It is not clear to me that the first is strictly stronger than the second.

Comment: @copper.hat Yes, right. What I said before was not fully correct. All in all, I find those definitions a bit strange. I would rather stick with "stability" and "uniform stability" as it always considered. I do not see the advantage of those definitions.

Comment: @KBS It has been a while, but I believe (decades ago) I saw something similar in the context of periodic solutions. The periodic solution is time varying, but represents an 'equilibrium' of sorts. But I do not recall where I saw that.

Comment: @copper.hat. Yes, so in that case, it is different because one trajectory is an equilibrium trajectory and we would like to study the evolution of solutions started nearby. The stability analysis of limit-cycles can be done this way, for instance. Contraction analysis also aims at studying what happens to two trajectories starting from close enough initial conditions. This may notably help establishing the existence of a globally asymptotically stable equilibrium point.

Comment: I had difficulty understanding the difference between both statements. The second statement fixes t_0 and the second not. The first says: the solution exists and is valid for any time greater the infimum 'a' given on definition of function f. This answer provides good pointers for your orientation.

Answer (score 2):

How it was phrased the first definition is *the standard definition of Lyapunov stability* in the case of a non-autonomous system. It is true that in many books and courses one speaks about Lyapunov stability of an equilibrium (at least initially) of an autonomous system, and it allows to gloss over a lot of subtle details (since the equilibrium solution is, e.g., defined for all future times automatically), but the original definition is given for *any* solution existing on $[t_0,+\infty)$ (it can be trivially reduced to the stability of the trivial (pun intended) solution of a modified system).

The second definition is a confusing version of the first one (and strictly speaking is incorrect since it assumes that the initial time moment is always $t_0=a$). I would suggest not use the notes @KBS referenced in the comments.

Comment: It seems to me that the first implies the second (take $t_0 = a$), so I would not consider it uniform.

Comment: @copper.hat Yes, you are correct.